# html.TextAreaFor and HtmlDecode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

question is very simple, I have this line of code within a template:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AnswerText, new { @class="Textarea", placeholder=Model.QuestionPlaceholder })
```

The problem is that sometimes AnswerText contains special characters like &, so I have tried the following:

```
@{var text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.AnswerText); }
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => text, new { @class="Textarea", placeholder=Model.QuestionPlaceholder })
```

And now the problem is that I can see properly the text, but it doesn't save.

I also have tried the following:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(m.AnswerText), new { @class="Textarea", placeholder=Model.QuestionPlaceholder })
```

but I get the following error:

[image]

update: I have tried the following:

```
<div class="InputField">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AnswerText)
</div>
```

but when I try to save & and then go back to the page and have a look I see &

How do you do this? It is Blazor, Razor, MVC, within an InputField

Comment: Why  is there a  [blazor] tag?  It looks like juist razor-pages.   Be clear about the platform you are using.

Comment: I am using Blazor, but this is within a template in a Razor page

Comment: A Razor page or a .razor file ?  Blazor is not MVC, you are still not clear.

Comment: it's .cshtml, mixing c#, html tags,

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like how I solved it, but it works. There is probably a better way:

```
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AnswerText, new { @class = "Textarea " + Model.ID, placeholder = Model.QuestionPlaceholder })
    <script>
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("Textarea " + @Model.ID)[0];
        elements.value = unescapeHtml(elements.value);
        function unescapeHtml(value) {
            return String(value)
                .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')...;

        }</script>
```